# What is the significance in determining the mass of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, mass

Was just wondering the importance of the mass of a black hole

Answer (score 1):

Because according to the "[no hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem)", the mass (along with the spin, and perhaps the overall charge, although most black holes are not expected to be charged) are the *only* externally observable properties of a black hole and completely determine any effect they might have on their surroundings.